# Bcrypt with two applications

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have two applications on same server one is Laravel and one is Blesta.

Laravel is fronted and all users details are handled by Blesta.

I want to use Laravel and bcrypt function for passwords, but after that I need to import user into Blesta (they are also using bcrypt) how I can sync that two bcrypt functions that they can use same password ?

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing. PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: `password_hash()` *is* bcrypt.

Answer (score 0):

bcrypt is bcrypt ...

If both applications use the same algorithm, it will work regardless of which application has created the hash.

If it doesn't work, then one of the apps isn't really using bcrypt.